# Automatically increment a field in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two tables in MongoDB connected through 1-to-many realtionship.

```
Itinerary:

 {
          name: String,
          locationsId: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "location" //1:m
          }],
          
        },
```

and

```
Location:

  {
          name: String,
          clicks: String
        },
```

I also have the save function in controller in order to add an itinerary into the DB.

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
const itinerary = new Itinerary({
      name: req.body.name
      locationsId: req.body.locationsId,
    });
  
    // Save Itinerary in the database
    itinerary
      .save(itinerary)
      .then(data => {
        res.send(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
       //show err
        });
      });
  };
```

I want that, when I use this route  `router.post("/", itineraries.create);` to automatically increase the number of clicks in Location table through locationId. Should I need to reference locationId embedded? And if yes, how should I write the increase, something like this? `{$inc: {'itineraryId.$.clicks': 1}}`

UPDATE: MY ITINERARY SCHEMA:

```
module.exports = mongoose => {

  const Itinerary = mongoose.model(
    "itinerary",
    mongoose.Schema(
      {
        name: String,
        locationsId: [{
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "location" //1:m
        }],
        
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    )
  );

  return Itinerary;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pre('save', callback)` or [post](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post) middleware of `mongoose` that executes before the `save`  method.

You should update `clicks` as `Number` in your `Location` schema.

```
const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    clicks: {   
        type: Number,
        integer: true,
    },
});
```

then define the `pre-save` middleware on `itinerarySchema`

Here is the updated schema as per the comments

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const itinerarySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  locationsId: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "location" 
  }],
}, { timestamps: true });

itinerarySchema.post('save', async function(doc,next) {
    // load the Location model
    const Location = mongoose.model('location');
    
    // get the location id
    const locationId = this.locationsId;

    try {
        await Location.findByIdAndUpdate(
            locationId,
            { $inc: { clicks: 1 } }
        )
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        next(error); 
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose => {

  const Itinerary = mongoose.model(
    "itinerary",
    itinerarySchema
  );

  return Itinerary;
};
```

and you can import this schema like

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Itinerary = require('./itinarySchema')(mongoose);
```

this middleware will execute before `itinerary.save()` and increment the `clicks` field

References :

- [Middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)
- [Model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html)
- [Pre](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre)
- [Post](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post)

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for you answer but I still need a little help:) My Itinerary Schema looks like this : 
``` module.exports = mongoose => {

  const Itinerary = mongoose.model(
    "itinerary",
    mongoose.Schema(
      {
        name: String,
        locationsId: [{
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "location" //1:m
        }],
        
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    )
  );

  return Itinerary;
};
```
 How ca I integrate that middleware in this? I tried to change the variable ItinerarySchema with Itinerary but it still doesn't work...

Comment: I updated it in the question

Comment: @prettyMaria I've updated my answer. Please look

Comment: I get this error when I try to post something to Itinerary TypeError: Itinerary is not a constructor<br>

Comment: How did you import the schema?It should be like `const Itinerary = require('./itinarySchema');`

Comment: I've updated the schema.. with the parameter `mongoose` in module exports. Let me know this worked for you.

Comment: no:(   "message": "Schema hasn't been registered for model \"Location\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)"
}

Comment: It will be an issue at the Mongoose Model name `Location`, It is case sensitive. Hope you have `mongoose.model('location',...)`. use it as `location`